# margin-top on legend inside a fieldset is not rendering

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML which is equivalent to the following:

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black">
  <fieldset style="margin: 0">
    <legend style="margin-top: 20px;">testing....</legend>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

My question is why does the `margin-top` on the legend [not render](https://jsfiddle.net/6v5Lwagz/)? I'd like to fix the issue with CSS only. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect as a result, but have you tried `padding-top` instead of `margin-top`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try padding instead. And it will work.

The reason why margin doesn't work because the distance between the border and the text content is called padding not margin.

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black">
  <fieldset style="margin: 0">
    <legend style="padding-top: 20px;">testing....</legend>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

I am no sure what exactly you are looking for. But you can also try padding in the container and vertically center the text within the container if that's what you want.

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black; padding-top: 20px;">
  <fieldset style="margin: 0">
    <legend>testing....</legend>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, then set `legend { float: left; }`:

```css
legend {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black">
  <fieldset style="margin: 0">
    <legend style="margin-top: 20px;">testing....</legend>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```